# Hidden Markov Model Coin Flips

Tags: markov-chains

Suppose in a system there are two possible states and each transition probability is decided by flipping a coin, e.g. transition probability from state 1 to 2 depends on outcome of the flip. How do you construct a MC in this problem to find steady-state probabilities?